# make query return related query

Tags: django, django-models

I have this model which tells me which users liked which images:

```
class Image:
    url = ....
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model())
```

This way users can like any number of images and multiple users can like the same image.

Now I want to return sets of images to the client but indicating which of them the currently logged user liked. So instead of having a list of Images (which would only indicate the URL) I want a list of objects with a URL and a boolean field, indicating if a specific user liked the respective image.

Comment: So you want to return all images, but flag the ones the currently logged in user liked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like

```
list = [ (img, bool(img.likes.filter(uid=CURRENT_UID))   for   img   in   Image.objects.all() ]
```

Your milage might vary: if you want to restrict the set of images, use a different filter instead of `Image.objects.all()`. Your user property might be called differently than `uid`, etc.

Or, alternatively if you are on 1.4 or higher, you can use the `prefetch_related` option on the QuerySet, see the Django documentation on it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

Comment: Hmm.. Is iterating the only solution? And doesn't that make a DB access for each image?

Comment: I don't quite understand; you wrote: "So instead of having a list of Images (which would only indicate the URL) I want a list of objects with a URL and a boolean field, indicating if a specific user liked the respective image.", so you'd have access them as well anyway? Also, as of my understanding with the above solution one query would be sent. The iteration happens over the returned QuerySet in python.

Comment: What about img.likes.filter? Isn't that a new query for each image? Anyway, in the meanwhile I found out about prefetch_related, so that's not an issue anymore. I'm accepting your answer, but maybe you should edit to include prefetch_related?